# Why is the UKSA not called the Ministry of Space?

Tags: history, uk-space

As far as I know, most agencies in His Majesty's Government have a name in the format *Ministry of Xyz*.  However, the space agency is called the *UK Space Agency* (UKSA).  Why?

Is it a case of copying the Americans, was the acronym MoS already taken, or something else?

Feel free to suggest a migration to Politics.SE if you think this would be more appropriate there.

Comment: it couldn't be a case of copying the Americans.  we have a National Aeronautics and Space **Administration**

Comment: I don't know if this is really true, but my first instinct is that if it was a ministry there'd have to be an MP in government with the title "Minister for Space".

Comment: @N.Virgo yep, that's the definition of a Ministry, it's led by a minister

Comment: If there's a Ministry of Space, there should also be a Ministry of Time.

Comment: @Ruslan Space is a big job, I wonder if it needs to be broken down into 3 separate ministries for each dimension.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There aren't many Ministries in the UK government any more, just:

1. Ministry of Defence
2. Ministry of Justice

The rest have been renamed to "Office" or "Department"

The UKSA is an [Executive Agency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_agency) of the [Department for Science, Innovation and Technology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Department_for_Science,_Innovation_and_Technology), not a [Ministerial Department](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Departments_of_the_Government_of_the_United_Kingdom) so wouldn't be called a ministry anyway.

See also https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations and [Why has the UK Government moved away from "Ministry of..." names?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69047/why-has-the-uk-government-moved-away-from-ministry-of-names)

Comment: Interesting.  So, unless in the future the UKSA gets split out of the _Department for Science, Innovation, and Technology_, it would never even be able to be renamed the _Ministry of Space_?  (Though from reading your linked answer, it seems more likely if that happened it would be _Department_ or _Office_, rather than _Ministry_.)

Comment: Yep, i don't think space is a big enough part of the UK economy to become it's own department any time soon

Comment: First I'd expect it to move to the Department for Transport when it goes from mostly experimental to mostly routine. I doubt it would ever get it's own department - even trains / buses / cars / planes don't get their own departments right now.